# Loading dojo library inside html code

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I have code which uses dojo 1.9.1  which looks like as below,

```
<html>
<head>
//some script1
//some script2
//some script3
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
//some html code
</body>
</html>
```

We are using dojo ready module inside script1 as ,

```
require(['dojo/ready'){
ready(function(){
    //init function xyz 
});
```

If we use above format, everything works fine. But whenever I move dojo.js above script1,
for eg.

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
//some script1
//some script2
//some script3
</head>
```

I start getting error in some script (say script2) ( some function is undefined ). Is there any pattern which I should follow ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this explains the particular problem but you have a huge syntax error.

```
require(['dojo/ready'){
ready(function(){
    //init function xyz 
});
```

should instead be

```
require(['dojo/ready'],function(ready){
  ready(function(){
      //init function xyz 
  });
});
```

This is because require takes 2 arguments -- first is the array of required modules. The second is a function (in this case anonymous) that takes those modules as arguments (this is where they are given variable names for use within. Inside of that anonymous function is where you define your ready event actions.

Comment: See also the following documentation which helped me:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/loader/amd.html#loader-amd